# Issue when Using c sockets in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, interop, libc

I am trying to create a socket using system sockets in c#.

I've made the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace test_socket

{
    public class Program
    {
        [DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "socket", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
    //public static extern int socket(AddressFamily domain, SocketType type, ProtocolFamily protocol);

    [DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "close", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int close(int handle);

    [DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "connect", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int connect(int socket, sockaddr_in addr, int socklen_t);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct sockaddr_in
    {
        public byte sin_len;
        public byte sin_family;
        public ushort sin_port;
        public uint sin_addr;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public byte[] sin_zero;
    };
        public static void Main() {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            int msock = socket(2, 1, 0); //AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0
            IPAddress ipa = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            int sock_struct_size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(sockaddr_in));
            sockaddr_in sin = new sockaddr_in()
            {
                sin_len = (byte)sock_struct_size,
                sin_family = 2, //2
                sin_port = (ushort)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((short)4569),
#pragma warning disable 618
                sin_addr = (uint)ipa.Address,
#pragma warning restore 618
                sin_zero = new byte[8] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
            };


            var test_sock = connect(msock, sin, sock_struct_size);

            Console.WriteLine(test_sock);
            Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
}
}
```

I'm always getting a -1 when trying to connect my socket.
I can of course connect to port 4569 locally:

## telnet 127.0.0.1 4569

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.

I have no idea what I've missed.

Replace the port 4569 with something that is opened, 22 (ssh) for example if testing the above code.

Tested with dotnetcore 3.1 and mac os 10.15.3

I made a sample c++ project to test sockets, it worked fine:

```
// Client side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define PORT 4569 
   
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
    int sock = 0, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    char *hello = "Hello from client"; 
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 
    printf("sizeof: %lu", sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

     printf("port: %hu", serv_addr.sin_port);
       
    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)  
    { 
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    uint x = serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr;
   
    printf("addr: %du", x);
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 
    send(sock , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 ); 
    printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
    valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024); 
    printf("%s\n",buffer ); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I checked the struct size and int values of port/ip, they also match

Comment: Is there a reason you went with interop?  Seems like reinventing the wheel to me.

Comment: Why aren't you using managed sockets? There's a System.Net assembly with all of this good stuff ready for you to use. You can start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: hi, The reason is that I am using an external lib which needs a socket handle:

int maapi_connect( int sock, const struct sockaddr* srv, int srv_sz);

Comment: It is possible to get the native handle from the managed `Socket` object. That said, your question can't be provided a good answer as it lacks a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Most likely you just have some network configuration issue, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow anyway, but if it's a coding error, you need to provide the necessary [mcve] so that people can reproduce and diagnose your error.

Comment: I can definitely tell it's not a network issue because I've tested this and I'm a network engineer, but I agree with the reproducible example. I'll provide a working c++ example, and non working c# example monday

Comment: Ok I have added a fiddle + instructions to original post.

Comment: Do not use an external web site to provide critical details for your question, not even dotnetfiddle.net. Your question must be entirely self-contained. That said, you should look at the actual error code being returned (e.g. `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`), as that will give you much more specific information about _what_ exactly you did wrong. Also, I am skeptical that your `sin_len` value is correct, given that you obtain it before you've initialized the `sin_zero` field (possibly the `MarshalAs` attribute handles this, but you should double-check).

Comment: @PeterDuniho, Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() gives 0.  I checked the sin_len, it is 16 as expected.
I made a c++ using the same functions and it works well. I compared the int representation of port and address in c++ and c# it's also the same...

Comment: Hence my use of _"e.g."_, not _"i.e."_. _Somewhere_ there is a useful error code. If you're in an environment where `GetLastWin32Error()` isn't productive, you need to call the function that does provide the detailed error code. Every sockets API implementation I've ever run into provides this mechanism. Based on your other representations about the values, that pretty much leaves a problem with your interop declarations...I suggest you look more closely at those.

Comment: Thanks, turns out you need to call the GetLastWin32Error right after socket function, I had a Console.Writeline between which resets the error code.
So I am getting code 22: #define EINVAL 22 /* Invalid argument */
I'll keep digging

Comment: Hello, I've used too many of my rep to put a bounty on this question, therefore I can't answer it anymore lol... Please find answer here for those interested: https://pastebin.com/raw/j6w8HLgp
Feel free to post this as an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@bmigette](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376587/bmigette) found the answer, but after putting a bounty on the question he does not have enought reputation to post it himself:

"[...] turns out you need to call the GetLastWin32Error right after socket function [...] Please find answer here for those interested: [pastebin.com/raw/j6w8HLgp](http://pastebin.com/raw/j6w8HLgp)"

In case the link is not available in the future, the working main function in the final solution is the following:

```
public unsafe static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine(" World");
    int msock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    IPAddress ipa = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    int sock_struct_size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(sockaddr_in));
    in_addr ina = new in_addr();
    var adbytes = ipa.GetAddressBytes();
    ina.s_addr[0] = adbytes[0];
    ina.s_addr[1] = adbytes[1];
    ina.s_addr[2] = adbytes[2];
    ina.s_addr[3] = adbytes[3];


    sockaddr_in sin = new sockaddr_in()
    {
        sin_family = 2, //2
        sin_port = (ushort)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((short)4569),

    };
    sin.sin_addr = ina; //.s_addr = (ushort)ipa.Address;

    Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(sin));

    var test_sock =connect(msock, (sockaddr*)&sin, sock_struct_size);
    var errno = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    Console.WriteLine(test_sock);
    Console.WriteLine(errno);

}
```

The necessary struct definitions can be found [here](https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.LibC/blob/827a7e88db7641505e0715400f25f708131a3e49/src/Sources/linux.common/socket.cs) and [here](https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.LibC/blob/451f31b477febad1bd46cd9869b7d6b5f05cbdc5/src/Sources/linux.common/types.cs#L292) too.